# sitefinity widget search table

Tags: sitefinity

I am creating a widgets that will collect data from a API and then populate a html table. I would like to add a search input text to the top of the table and allow the user to search the html table and filter the result base off the input. what is the best option to do that in sitefinity ?

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Filter Results..." />
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Meeting Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (BlogsViewModel objBlogs in objBlogs.BlogsViewModelViewModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@objBlogs.Name</td>
                <td>@objPanel.Decs</td>
            </tr>
        }
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean... KendoUI is a licensed part of Sitefinity

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

Comment: Is that the only way? I update my post with the table can I use the Frontend.Search or bootstrap?

Comment: It's not, you can really do whatever you want on the client, it's technically outside of Sitefinity right... it's just it's pretty comprehensive. It can take your html generated table and create a functional grid from it.

If you don't do that, you can have your search do a postback and filter based on querystring

OR... render your blog posts as a client object into some js object and manipulate fully clientside outside of Sitefintiy with a rest api.

Comment: Is it just adding ‘@(Html.Kendo().’ To the cshtml file?

Comment: If you just need it on that ONE page, like you're only gonna use the grid use their docs and load just the grid with the cdn. KendoWeb is big, KendoAll is way bigger